# iOS : Unable to import CoreWLAN framework in iOS8

Tags: ios, xcode6, osx-yosemite, corewlan

I am trying to Import CoreWLAN framework for wireless network development. I got reference pdf from mac developer site as https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/CoreWLANFrameworkRef/CoreWLANFrameworkRef.pdf

But I am unable to Import CoreWLAN frame in Project.

Statement 
@import CoreWLAN; 
gives Error -- Module CoreWLAN not found

Comment: For developing a Mac application or iOS? Looks like it's for Mac only and not available on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is tagged with the iOS tag, you're presumably trying to import CoreWLAN for an iOS project, which isn't possible.

You can use the SystemConfiguration framework if all you're trying to do is access the name of the currently connected network. See the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo) for more.

Answer (score 0):

CoreWlan isn't available for iOS, it's a Cocoa Framework. If you need the same functionality on iOS, please have a look at the [NEHotspotConfigurationManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotconfigurationmanager).